# Solution to Remove Duplicates from Sorted List Not Working

Tags: swift, linked-list

I am trying to delete duplicate node from a linked list. My solution shows the wrong output; how do I resolve this ?
Your input
[1,1,2]
Output
[1,1]
Diff
Expected
[1,2]

```
func deleteDuplicates(_ head: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        
        var dummyNode = ListNode(0, head)
        var p1: ListNode? = dummyNode
        var p2 = head
      
        while  p1!.next != nil &&  p2!.next != nil{
            if p1!.val != p2!.val {
                p1 = p1!.next
                p2 = p2!.next
            }
            else if p1!.val == p2!.val{
                p2!.next = p2?.next!.next 
            }
        }
        return head
    }
```

[image]

Comment: its an array right?

Comment: Its a Linked List

Comment: can you give a sample dataset for ListNode?

Comment: is that contains array of nodes something like this  [1,1,2]?

Comment: @Jok3r Input: head = [1,1,2,3,3]
Output: [1,2,3] https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

Comment: its an integer array anyhow right?

Answer (score 0):

```
func deleteDuplicates(_ head: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
    var temp = head 
    while temp != nil {

        if temp?.val == temp?.next?.val {
            temp?.next = temp?.next?.next
        }else {
            temp = temp?.next
        }
    }
    return head
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution what can you please point out what's wrong with my code in terms of the output value?